# Как правильно переадресовать юзера на главную страницу после login'а и logout'а в Django?

Tags: django

Всем доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане!)
Django начал изучать буквально недавно, пришла мысль сделать простенький блог для начала, где на главной странице сразу будет выводиться список статей из базы, отсортированный по дате (т.е. при переходе по ссылке ***my_site.ru/*** сразу срабатывает вьюха **main_views.index**, которая в шаблон подгружает все статьи
Решил не делать отдельные страницы для ввода логина и пароля, а сделать это всё в главном шаблоне ***index.html***
Собссно вопрос: как правильно переадресовать юзера на главную страницу после login'а и logout'а в Django?

вот структура проекта:

- my_project
- |
- |--- articles
- |
- |--- accounts

код **my_project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views as main_views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('', main_views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

код **accounts/urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login), 
    path('logout', views.logout,
]
```

код **accounts/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import auth

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            context = {'user': user}
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
        else:
            context = {'user': None}
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
]
```

вот кусок шаблона ***index.html*** с формой

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <div class="user"> Привет, {{ user.get_full_name }}!
         <form action="accounts/logout" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="submit" value="Выйти" />
         </form>
    </div>
{% else %}
   {% if form.errors %}
         <p class="error">Сожалеем, вы неправильно ввели логин или пароль</p>
   {% endif %}
   <form action="accounts/login" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       <label for="username">Логин:</label>
       <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
       <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
       <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

       <input type="submit" value="login" />
       <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
{%  endif %}
```

при авторизации пользователя перекидывает на главную страницу, что и логично, ведь я рендерю главный шаблон и при этом статьи не отображаются, что тоже вроде как очевидно, ведь не вызывается нужная вьюха) так вот как её правильно вызвать? можно подключить в accounts/views.py вьюху index из my_project/views.py, но чую одним местом, что это не комльфо ибо создаются перекрестные связи, а это не гибко))

и еще.... после того как пользователь решил разлогиниться и кликает на кнопку выхода вообще выдается ошибка

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/accounts/logout
```

вот тут я вообще не могу понять почему так... почему обращение идёт 2 раза к accounts

прошу сильно не ругаться на меня)) долго искал решение на всяких форумах, но везде делают для авторизации отдельную страницу, а так как я хочу - не нашёл инфы
Буду очень признателен за помощь да и вообще за любые подсказки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4870619/13794578 думаю что это поможет

Answer (score 0):

пробовал сделать так:

в модуле **accounts/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import auth

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        url_from = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect(url_from)


def logout(request):
    url_from = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect(url_from)
```

вместо **render** использовал **redirect** и перенаправлял на страницу откуда был запрос
в этом случае ***logout*** отрабатывает прекрасно, а ***login*** виснет, выдаёт код переадресации 302 и висит...

мож кто подскажет почему?